# Filter logstash does not work with Grok Debugger

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I use Grok Debugger to verify my pattern which is: %{DATA:evolution} %{DATA:value}

But the problem that it does not read the content of the variable "value".

If I want to use two successive strings, how can I do that please?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `WORD` instead of `DATA` which captures also spaces:

```
%{WORD:evolution} %{WORD:value}
```

Results:

```
{
  "evolution": [
    [
      "Send"
    ]
  ],
  "value": [
    [
      "functionHandle"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.